# Преобразование к QGraphicsItem

Tags: c++, qt, ооп

Пишу программу, пользуясь [примером](http://doc.crossplatform.ru/qt/4.4.3/graphicsview-diagramscene.html)

Меня там интересуют два класса: DiagramItem и Arrow. 
Arrow я оставляю практически без изменений, а DiagramItem заменяю на собственный CircuitElement, который наследуется от QGraphicsItem.

Далее в одном из методов Arrow вызывается функция mapFromItem(...), первый аргумент которой const QGraphicsItem*.
Я передаю туда объект своего типа CircuitElement и преобразование не происходит.
Хотя в примере с  DiagramItem работает.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, всё дело в том, что функция класса QGraphicsItem, которую Вы вызываете, не объявлена как виртуальная.